# Emulator low speed in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, ide

I had install android studio 1.0 in two days ago, but when I want run a emulator, I should wait for run more than 10 minutes.(my system is Asus N53sv and my emulator is google_Nexus_API 17 x86).
Now what do am I?

Comment: Try https://www.genymotion.com, it's faster than common emulator

Answer (score 0):

- Emulators are **slow.**

  They're bootstrapping the entire mobile device and its components, and you'd require a machine with decent hardware to run one quickly.
- Emulators are **memory intensive.**  Android Studio happens to be as well, and if [this is your machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004L9M4QY), then it's not going to load very fast at all.  I'm surprised that it's loading at all!

There's not much you could do outside of upgrading your machine, though.

Comment: How I can load a machine with decent hardware to run one quickly?

Comment: It'd cost money though to upgrade your machine.